# scikit-learn tfidf / countvector classify too slow

Tags: scikit-learn

everyone, I'm doing chinese fake news detection task, that I transform text into vector by scikit-learn TfidfVectorizer and CountVectorizer. Training dataset size is about 3000 and testing dataset size is about 750, and the both count vector and tf-idf vectors' data dimension is about 11000. When I try one of those to classify, it's just took 5s, but the other took 15 minutes to train and test. The classifiers that I used were SVM / XGBoost / Bagging.

```
# word embedding

tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(lowercase=False, max_df=1.0, min_df=0.0006)
tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
tfidf_train = tfidf_vectorizer.transform(train_data) 
tfidf_test = tfidf_vectorizer.transform(test_data)

bow_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(lowercase=False, max_df=1.0, min_df=0.007)
bow_vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
bow_train = bow_vectorizer.transform(train_data)
bow_test= tfidf_vectorizer.transform(test_data)

# classification

model = sklearn.svm.SVC(kernel='rbf', degree=3, gamma='scale', coef0=0.0, shrinking=True, probability=False,  　tol=0.001, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, verbose=False, max_iter=-1, decision_function_shape='ovr', break_ties=False, random_state=None)

model.fit(tfidf_train, y_train)
prediction = model.predict(tfidf_test)
```

I try to restart compiler, and find out, if the type of word embedding that I run at first time then it will finsh train and test in 5s, then the other will take 15 minutes.

Restarting computer or compiler is not work.

Comment: And I tried to reduce dimension from 11,088 to 1421, but still cost 15 minutes to train and test.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.